# Apache .htaccess redirect to index.php not working for subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working with the .htaccess file inside the website's main public directory. I don't have access to php.ini or any other root operations (but can if necessary).
I have a framework that is similar to wordpress in that I need all requests to go through index.php in the root directory. This works for the initial request (as it's just index.php), but any service or subdirectory request keeps returning a 404.

This is my current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone please help solve this?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php`

Comment: Still gives a 404 to requests underneath of the root /, however I noticed if I explicity enable "RewriteEngine on" in the .htaccess, it then gives a Forbidden response for all requests. What gives?

Comment: invert flags `!-f` `!-d`. it means that uri is not a file or a directory

Comment: Still gives a 404 for the subdirectories. ie:
/ returns the site index.php just fine, but /service/api-request returns a 404. If I enable RewriteEngine on it denies permission on all requests, so I think I need to solve that problem first.

Comment: Hey all. I chmod'd the entire directory, but it's still giving forbidden when I try to access any url. Why would this happen? My .htaccess is still as it is above, with !-f and !-d.

Comment: Solution was to add "options +FollowSymLinks" at the top of the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

If it doesn't solve, then Check if the mod_rewrite module is enabled on your server, You can check it using the following php function

```
 <?php
 print_r(apache_get_modules());
  ?>
```

This function returns an array of all activated modules on the apache server.

Comment: Thanks. mod_rewrite is enabled, but I'm still getting permission errors. Going to try to get root access to adjust the permissions before I continue with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Adding Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch to the top of the .htaccess solved the permissions issues.